# Convert Curves to Grease Pencil?

Tags: python, bezier-curves, grease-pencil

I'd like to know if there's a way/add-on to convert curves to Grease Pencil strokes? I know you can convert in the other direction, but I can't find anything to create Grease Pencil strokes from curves.

In attempting to setup guides for a model I'm working on, did so using curves. I'm now thinking GP would have been the better option, and would rather not have to recreate my guides.

[image: Rubbery Ducky curve guides (traced from reference photos)]

Comment: Why don't you use the curves as guidelines instead?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First convert your curves in to mesh objects, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> > *Mesh from Curve/Meta/Surf/Text*.

Now just copy and paste the script below into blender's text editor, then with your object still selected press *Run Script*.

This script below will draw grease pencil strokes on the [active object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21050/2217).

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

obj = bpy.context.object
mesh = obj.data
scene = bpy.context.scene

pencil = bpy.data.grease_pencil.new("pencil")
scene.grease_pencil = pencil

layer = pencil.layers.new("layer", set_active=True)
frame = layer.frames.new(scene.frame_current)

for edge in mesh.edges:
    stroke = frame.strokes.new()
    stroke.draw_mode = '3DSPACE'

    stroke.points.add(2)
    stroke.points[0].co = obj.matrix_world * Vector(mesh.vertices[edge.vertices[0]].co)
    stroke.points[1].co = obj.matrix_world * Vector(mesh.vertices[edge.vertices[1]].co)
```

Thanks to CoDEmanX for his making a grease pencil through bpy [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/24712/2217).

Comment: or if you don't want to manually convert Curve to mesh first. use this: https://gist.github.com/zeffii/3ff4af3bb359c7d5eb0a

Comment: I would love to see an example of this for blender 2.78.  I have tried quite a few things that do not seem to work or crash blender.  If I add each edge as a stroke, the next time gpencil is used it crashes blender.  If I add all the verts individually to avoid the crash, I don't have a palette and if I add a palette via data...it crashes blender.

Comment: For blender 2.8, for curves and meshes, https://gist.github.com/iszotic/97eb7b479e38b51d8c02ec667cb0e559, use F3 or space to search for the operator

Answer (score 11):

You may also fake a look of a *Grease Pencil*. Select your curve, go to the *Shape* panel in a curve data header, change the *Fill* type to ***Full***. Increase the ***Depth*** value under ***Bevel:*** to give a curve some thickness. Give it a new material also and change its settings as pictured below. Now you have an editable imitation of a *Grease Pencil*.
[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 4):

As a follow-up to @David script, I noticed that it creates a new Grease Pencil Data every time the script is run. This can make it annoying if you simply want each mesh as a new GP layer in the existing data.

To instead make it create a new layer on the existing Grease Pencil Data:

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

def convert_curve_to_gp(obj):

    #---- CHANGED ----
    scene = bpy.context.scene
    mesh = obj.data

    layer = scene.grease_pencil.layers.new("layer", set_active=True)
    frame = layer.frames.new(scene.frame_current)
    #---- /CHANGED ----

    mesh = obj.to_mesh(scene, apply_modifiers=False, settings='PREVIEW')
    for edge in mesh.edges:
        stroke = frame.strokes.new()
        stroke.draw_mode = '3DSPACE'
        stroke.points.add(2)
        stroke.points[0].co = obj.matrix_world * Vector(mesh.vertices[edge.vertices[0]].co)
        stroke.points[1].co = obj.matrix_world * Vector(mesh.vertices[edge.vertices[1]].co)

    bpy.data.meshes.remove(mesh)

obj = bpy.context.object
convert_curve_to_gp(obj)
```

Answer (score 4):

If you like to do this procedurally, you can use Sverchok Add-On to access the existing Grease Pencil data block and then modify it on the fly using nodes. A quick example, below I have 3 curves joined and then I draw Grease Pencil using this node tree:

GIST:
https://gist.github.com/cfa9cf5b707b909965e2b4956ad0ce25

[image]

This will potentially change as Grease Pencil is currently being developed into real object.

Comment: This does not work for me in 0.5.9.6 Please provide a working Blender if you can. thanks

Comment: Yes, actually something might have changed in Grease Pencil.. maybe with 2.8 the node will need to be revisited. I will check now...