# Can I import an image file so it can be used in grease pencil?

Tags: import, image, grease-pencil

Can I import an image file so it can be used in grease pencil instead of drawing? I would have problems with hand drawn image in Blender due to a stroke.

Specifically I'll have difficulty drawing vertical and horizontal lines with grease pencil. I need to import some line drawings of buildings, and the way that Grease pencil enables you to draw in 3D space appeals to me.

If so How would I import exactly, into Blender generally?

Comment: are you comfortable making Curves? if so that would allow you to skip a lot of steps..

Comment: Thanks, that's positive then. I can use Illustrator or similar. It's just that I'll have difficulty drawing vertical and horizontal lines with grease pencil. I need to import some line drwgs of buildings, and the way that Grease pencil enables you to draw in 3d space appeals to me.
How would I import exactly, into Blender generally? or specific place. Baz

Comment: Now you've elaborated on the scenario, I'm less inclined to think that Grease pencil will be any faster than extruding vertices, and snapping to axes.

Comment: @bazzart If you can use something like Inkscape to "vectorize" an image, you could get a svg vector file from your image (neeeds some practice and it strongly depends from the image and desired result...). Then import the svg into blender. Just another (more convoluted) option, but...

Comment: yeah, once you have curves (easy to import from svg) then you can use scripts to convert to gp lines. see related question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36140/convert-curves-to-grease-pencil

Answer (score 1):

HOW TO ADD BACKGROUND OR REFERENCE IMAGES IN BLENDER 2D GREASE PENCIL THIS EVEN APPLIES TO GENERAL MODE

When you start in 2D animation Mode. Your option will be set to "DRAW" mode instead of 
"object mode" you need to Switch from Draw mode to object Mode.

When you switch to object mode you will notice new button options and one of them is "Add"
you can use that or just Shift A.

1 -shift+A to add background image or reference Image.

2 - Shift + A to add Grease Pencil then select blank or stroke or the monkey if you don't know what they each mean, google it. if you just want to draw select blank.

3 - now change mode from object mode to "DRAW MODE" 
    enjoy.

Comment: Problem with this is that the images won't (obviously) be rendered, as they are reference/background images. But that's probably configurable some where as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use snaping to create vertical lines.Select "line" snapping. Also, press shift+4 or shift 6 to rotate the view of the camera in camera view. That's how you can draw vertical lines.