# Is there a way to convert an imported svg into a grease pencil layer?

Tags: grease-pencil, svg

I have an svg path, made in illustrator that I would like to import into Blender and convert into a grease pencil animation. is this a thing that is possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround is possible i.a. with a script, but your imported .svg needs to be curves in the first place. See [the answers to the following question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36140/convert-curves-to-grease-pencil)