# How to Convert Curves to Grease Pencil in Blender 3?

Tags: grease-pencil, svg

Using the Import-Export SVG addon, I imported an SVG as curves so I can make a 2D animation with it. Only problem is, curve layers don't evaluate in 2D-style top-down layer stack, so all the layers show through each other. I need a way to convert them to grease pencils so the layers stay behind or in front of each other depending on index position. [This](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36140/convert-curves-to-grease-pencil) looked promising, but the solution is a script which no longer functions in Blender 3.

Note: `Import > SVG as Grease Pencil` only seems to work for really simple SVG files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can convert multiple objects by selecting all of them with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> and then clicking any object with <kbd>RMB</kbd> *> Convert To > Grease Pencil*.