# Convert animated 3d curve to Grease Pencil

Tags: bezier-curves, grease-pencil, alembic

When I select the curve and do convert to -> grease pencil the animation is lost. This is really frustrating.

Is there any way to maintain the animation of an animated 3d curve? In my case I use an alembic import.

Comment: Could you tell us more about the animation you're trying to keep ? If it's the position of the object in 3D space, it's easy to transfer from one object to another.

Comment: It's not only the object (transform), but also the shape that changes :/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've already seen it, but [this topic](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36140/convert-curves-to-grease-pencil?rq=1) shows many ways to convert curves to Grease Pencil.